# How to make a data frame with function in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

For some basic publications I have to make almost same codes for many tables. So I have to make a quite fast code to make data frames from files and to make some same operations with data using only one same formula.

Example:

```
# Creating function
basic_sum <- function (place, DF, factor_col, sum) {

  # Uploading data.frame
  DF <- read.csv (place, sep = ";")

  # Converting to factor
  for (i in factor_col) {
   DF [, i] <- as.factor (DF [, i])
  }

  # Summary
  sum <- summary (DF)
  View (sum)
}
```

Than I'm running that code and get a function **basic_sum**

If I want to work with my Data I call this function with arguments:

```
basic_sum (place = "~/DataFrame.csv", DF = DataFrame,
           factor_col = c (1, 6 : 11), sum = DF_sum)
```

After running it nothing happens. I mean, I don't have anything new in Environment. No new data, no new vars or something else.

In my thoughts it seems that finally I have to get:

1) data.frame "**DataFrame**", that was uploaded *DataFrame.csv*;

2) 1st, 6th, 7th and all other columns until 11th will be *factor*

3) data.frame "**DF_sum**" with summary of all my columns from "DataFrame"

4) I will see data.frame "**DF_sum**".

Well, I see all of it in console, but I need it in Environment and to save it somewhere.

Seems that I'm doing something wrong... But I don't know what.

P.S.: If I try to run it without **function** (of course replacing **DF** to **DataFrame**, **factor_col** to **с (1, 6 : 11)** and so on...) everything is all right. But I have to rewrite code every time or at lest replace all DF and other that bother me.

With great regards,

Dmitrii

Comment: Try adding `return(sum)` as the last line of the function. R will return the last line of a function by default, and right now the last line is `View`, which does not return any values.

Comment: Thats so sad, but nothing has happened. I mean nothing new. I still see `sum` in *Console* and nothing new in *Environment*